# Firebase Realtime Database, ListAdapter, DiffUtil and ViewModel

Tags: firebase, android-recyclerview, android-livedata, android-diffutils, android-listadapter

I am trying to create a list view using `Recycler View` and display a list. Lets say what I am trying to display is like a typical chat screen - image, message, sender_name etc.

So all this data is stored in Firebase Realtime Database. I am also using `ViewModel` and would like to use `DiffUtil` for efficiency - since messages can be deleted, edited, starred, new ones added etc.. Due to `DiffUtil`, I am using a `ListAdapter`.

The issue I am facing is that the `ListAdapter` needs a `List` and I use a `ChildEventListener`.

How do I now observe changes from Firebase using `LiveData` and then update my list so that I can pass back into my `DiffUtil`? So if I add a new message, I'd like that to be added to my `RecyclerView` and I'd like to do that using `DiffUtil` since the list can also be updated.

What I found through research was that I might need to use `Room` for this purpose and observe the query for changes - so observe something like a `getAllMessages()` method which would return the complete list and then I can use that to pass into my `DiffUtil`. That sounds like an overkill to me - the implementation of `Room`.

Any pointers or suggestions on how I can achieve my need?

Here is the structure of my db:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this out by doing the following in my `ViewModel`.

```
private val _message = MutableLiveData<List<TextListModel>>()

val message: LiveData<List<TextListModel>>
        get() = _message

//...

private val eventListener =
        object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                Timber.e("Error!! ${databaseError.toException()}")
            }

            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                val listOfMessages : MutableList<TextListModel> = mutableListOf()

                for(msg in dataSnapshot.children) {
                    val item = msg.getValue(TextListModel::class.java)
                    listOfMessages.add(item!!)
                }

                _message.value = listOfMessages
            }
        }
```

In my fragment I observe `message` and perform `adapter.submitList(newList)` when there is an update.

This downloading of data using `ValueEventListener` is concerning though since it pulls the data from under the node. I am checking on how to use `ChildEventListener` for my purposes.

**EDIT**

Seems like Value events don't download the full tree over! Value events work with the data in the local state and only downloads the delta.

Some more information in this [Youtube Video from 2016](https://youtu.be/cYinms8LurA?t=481)!

Answer (score 0):

if you dare to start programming an app, you won't be able to get along with Room soon. if you take this step, SQL knowledge is necessary as well...so don't be shy and just dare to do it

GGK